# mv error in destination file in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and my system does not use apt-get or yum,

Tags: mv

I'm trying to install FDR on Ubuntu. whenever I want to install FDR4 in `/usr/local` with this:

```
mv ~/Downloads/fdr4 /usr/local/fdr4
```

but error occurs with message

```
mv: mising destination file operand
```

Comment: i have downloaded the software and trying to install FDR according to the instructions, but i m unable to pick the installation location and copy the files to the locations. i m using mv for this and getting error.

Comment: yup i m using sudo in the system, also the whole directory location cant be placed in single line, so i use multiple lines but didnt use enter key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading `gz` files and extracting and moving them is not the best way to install a software in Ubuntu. You should use `sudo apt-get` or more recent `sudo apt` commands to install software from the command line whenever possible.

The instructions below are from https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/projects/fdr/manual/gui/getting_started.html

> If your distribution uses apt-get (e.g. Debian or **Ubuntu**), then the
>   following commands can be used to install FDR:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/projects/fdr/downloads/debian/ fdr release\n" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fdr.list'
wget -qO - http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/projects/fdr/downloads/linux_deploy.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fdr
```

Comment: my system does not use apt-get or yum,